# Getting "state not found" during msal loginRedirect method

Tags: msal.js

I am attempting to implement msal 2 in my React application. I'm using the msal-react-samples/default as the template for my work. I am able to see me login page and login using the loginRedirect method. But upon returning to my application I'm getting the following error. I saw that someone asked a very similar question (65375241). But it looks like the user abandoned it. I have included additional information below.

**errorCode: "state_not_found"
errorMessage: "State not found:  Cached State"**

**Additional Information**

- Authenticating into ADB2C
- MsalConfig:
  `{ auth: { clientId: "REDACTED" authority: "REDACTED" knownAuthorities:["Redacted, Same as authority"], redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/AuthTest", navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false }, cache: { cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",  storeAuthStateInCookie: false,  }, system: { loggerOptions: { ...(logger options from sample) } }`
- Authentication worked previously with MSAL1.
- I'm aware that as of 1/7/2021 the msal-react package is not meant for production environments. I could attempt to change to just use just the msal-browser package if that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my own error by looking at the the MSAL git repo issue
[@azure/msal-browser redirect not working correctly](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2796)

I will describe my issue here to assist anyone else that has this same error.

It was caused because I had used the addEventCallback method improperly.

I had it implemented in my code as a simple function call. But it needs needs to be put into a useEffect and also issue the removeEventCallback method after consuming it.

I had

```
instance.addEventCallback((message) => {
    console.log(message)
 })
```

rather than

```
useEffect(() => {
        const callbackId = instance.addEventCallback((message) => {
            console.log(message)
        })
        return () => {
            if (callbackId) {
                instance.removeEventCallback(callbackId);
            }
        }
    }, [instance])
```